# Sidebar Docusaurus CSS V2

Tags: sidebar, docusaurus

I have 2 question.

1. Is it possible to change a sidebar backgorund colour based on it's id?
   For example, in sidebar.js, I have sidebar1 and sidebar2. I want sidebar 1 to have a different colour than sidebar 2.
2. How do I input the default sidebar on a custom page? I created a new page, however, it only contain the default navbar and footer only, no sidebar.

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

For now you can swizzle the theme sidebar and add a class according to the sidebar name.

If you open an issue, we could automatically add that class on the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

1. Add `customCss` to your `theme` config([docs](https://docusaurus.io/docs/styling-layout)), e.g.:

   ```js
   {
     // ...
     presets: [
       [
         'classic',
         /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
         ({
           // ...
           theme: {
             customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
           }
         })
       ]
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Add `"className": "category1"` to `_category_.json`
3. Add class of same name to `src/css/custom.css`:

   ```css
   .category1 > .menu__link {
     color: red;
   }
   ```

   - NOTE: the element that receives the class contains an `a` element of class `.menu__link` that defines the default color, so override that.